# Docker-compose with Django, Redis, Gunicorn, Uvicorn, Nginx: Is my Nginx working?

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn, uvicorn

I am trying to use docker-compose to setup the following:
Container 1: gunicorn to serve django WSGI + uvicorn to serve django ASGI (for websockets)
Container 2: redis server for websockets
Container 3: nginx server to handle HTTP/websocket requests and direct them to WSGI/ASGI respectively

However, after docker-compose up, my nginx server doesn't seem to be working.
I can run the app stack with no issues in communications between redis/django but I don't see my ngnix working anywhere.
My questions are:
1) How do I know that my nginx server is working? (i.e requests are not sent directly to gunicorn/uvicorn but via nginx)
2) Is this the correct setup?

Heres my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web_app_server:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: web_app_server
    ports:
      - "8007:8765"
      - "8000:8000"

  redis_server:
    restart: always
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:  # <-- wait for djangoapp to be "ready" before starting this service
      - web_app_server
```

At the end of the Dockerfile for building the web_app_server in docker-compose, I have

```
CMD ./dockerfile_start.sh
```

where dockerfile_start.sh contains:

```
killall gunicorn
killall uvicorn
./gunicorn_wsgi.sh &
P1=$!
./uvicorn_asgi.sh &
P2=$!
wait $P1 $P2
```

with gunicorn_wsgi.sh:

```
gunicorn locallibrary.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8765
```

and uvicorn_asgi.sh

```
uvicorn locallibrary.asgi:application --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

My nginx conf file ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:

```
upstream django_app {
    server web_app_server:8765;
}

upstream socker_server {
    server web_app_server:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/nlp_app/NLP_Toolkit_App/src/Django/locallibrary;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://django_app;
    }

    location /2/ {
        proxy_pass http://socker_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is the printout after docker-compose up:

```
Creating nlp_toolkit_app_redis_server_1_c545837e3c21 ... done
Creating web_app_server                              ... done
Creating nlp_toolkit_app_nginx_1_c5c6fdde67ba        ... done
Attaching to web_app_server, nlp_toolkit_app_nginx_1_46069f8268c6, nlp_toolkit_app_redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9
web_app_server    | ./dockerfile_start.sh: 1: ./dockerfile_start.sh: killall: not found
web_app_server    | ./dockerfile_start.sh: 2: ./dockerfile_start.sh: killall: not found
web_app_server    | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
web_app_server    | INFO:     Started reloader process [10] using statreload
web_app_server    | [2020-05-11 11:36:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:C 11 May 2020 11:36:02.774 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:C 11 May 2020 11:36:02.774 # Redis version=6.0.1, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:C 11 May 2020 11:36:02.774 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
web_app_server    | [2020-05-11 11:36:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8765 (9)
web_app_server    | [2020-05-11 11:36:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.775 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.775 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.775 # Server initialized
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.775 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.775 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
redis_server_1_58ff0cf70dd9 | 1:M 11 May 2020 11:36:02.776 * Ready to accept connections
web_app_server    | [2020-05-11 11:36:02 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
web_app_server    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py:9: NumbaDeprecationWarning: An import was requested from a module that has moved location.
web_app_server    | Import of 'jit' requested from: 'numba.decorators', please update to use 'numba.core.decorators' or pin to Numba version 0.48.0. This alias will not be present in Numba version 0.50.0.
web_app_server    |   from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
web_app_server    | INFO:     generated new fontManager
web_app_server    | INFO:     Better speed can be achieved with apex installed from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex .
web_app_server    | INFO:     PyTorch version 1.4.0 available.
web_app_server    | INFO:     PyTorch version 1.4.0 available.
web_app_server    | INFO:     Better speed can be achieved with apex installed from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex .
web_app_server    | INFO:     PyTorch version 1.4.0 available.
web_app_server    | INFO:     Better speed can be achieved with apex installed from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex .
web_app_server    | INFO:     Better speed can be achieved with apex installed from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex .
web_app_server    | INFO:     Started server process [12]
web_app_server    | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
web_app_server    | INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
web_app_server    | INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try to check the logs from each container. `docker-compose logs <service name>`.

Comment: when i do 'sudo docker-compose logs nginx' it just says 'Attaching to nlp_toolkit_app_nginx_1_46069f8268c6'